# Python - second subprocess won't open if sys.argv containts "&" character

Tags: python, ffmpeg, argv, sys

I've got a Python script which download a video using `youtube-dl` and then extract frames from it using `ffmpeg`. This is the code:

```
def DownloadVideo():
    output_file = "/Users/francesco/Desktop/SOURCE/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s"
    check_call(["youtube-dl","--output", output_file, "--restrict-filenames", "-f", "best", sys.argv[1]])

def ConvertVideo(video):
    DEST = "/Users/francesco/Desktop/OUTPUT"
    SOURCE = "/Users/francesco/Desktop/SOURCE"
    ffmpeg_path = "/Users/francesco/Desktop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg"
    video_path = SOURCE + "/" + video
    dest_path = DEST + "/" + os.path.splitext(video)[0] + "-%d.png"
    check_call([ffmpeg_path, "-v", "0", "-i", video_path, "-f", "image2", dest_path])

def Main():
    DownloadVideo()
    for video in os.listdir("/Users/francesco/Desktop/SOURCE"):
       ConvertVideo(video)
```

I run the command `python myscript.py myvideolink` and everything goes fine in the download process, but the ConvertVideo doesn't start, it just get frozen for a couple of seconds and then the program exits.

If I try to run the same command skipping the `DownloadVideo()` (with the video already downloaded in the folder) it doens't work too, but if I use `python myscript.py` without the argv[1], the ffmpeg process works! Why this happens?

Update: I've tried to remove the `-v 0` option in ffmpeg to see what actually happens, ffmpeg process starts, but get frozen like this:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Update 2: Turns out that this happens only when the argument (which is a link) contains the character "&". Anyone knows why this is a problem for ffmpeg? He's not neither using the arg variable...

Comment: `check_call` is going to slow down your program a significant amount as it waits until the conversion is done. Since you are going to be looping through video file names and want to convert each one in the directory, I suggest using [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: But isn't Popen going to open multiple parallel processes? I mean if I have 20 video in the source folder, it will open 20 parallel processes?

Comment: Yeah, which will make it run faster. or better yet create a thread class and that way you can handle errors better

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're specifying an output location that already exists, and FFmpeg is asking you wether you want to overwrite the file or not, waiting for "y" (or anything else, which would mean no) on stdin. To prevent it from doing so, use the "-y" option, which prevents it from asking that question and force-overwrites the output file.

Comment: The output folder is empty and ffmpeg always ask me if I want to overwrite the output if already exists, I've tried to delete the "-v 0" to see what happens, and ffmpeg starts, it just got stuck like in the log I've posted.

Comment: I found out that the problem is when the arg contains the "&" character. Do you know how this can be a problem for ffmpeg?